# Why does [].slice.call() return "empty slots"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap a complicated object in an array of length 1 (i.e., the object is the only entry in the array), and am hoping to do this in the class constructor . . . To get there, I've been playing with [].slice.call(), and when I was playing around for testing purposes, I tried the following in the console:

```
foo = {"a":{"a1":1},"b":{"b1":2},length: 2};
[].slice.call(foo);
```

I got back an array of length two, with "two empty slots."

Given that `[].slice.call({"a": 1, "b": 2, length: 2}` yielded `[1, 2]`, I would have expected to get an array of length two as follows:
[{"a1":1},{"b1":2}], instead of "two empty slots". Does [].slice.call only work on "one-dimensional" objects, or is there something else going on? Many thanks in advance if anyone can please clarify!

Comment: `Given that [].slice.call({"a": 1, "b": 2, length: 2} yielded [1, 2]` I can't reproduce. I get `(2) [empty × 2]`

Comment: Mea Culpa! I was simplifying and ended up over-simplifying . . . It was actually `[].slice.call({"0": "a", "1": b, length 2})` that produced ["a", "b"] . . . so am I to surmise that the object that gets sliced needs to provide `indices` as `keys` in order for `[].slice.call()` to work?

Answer (score 3):

`slice` will only iterate over *numeric-indexed* properties of an object. See the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.10):

> 5. Let relativeStart be ToInteger(start).

(so if `start` is `undefined`, like when `slice` is called with no arguments, `relativeStart` is `0`)

Then, it will iterate over numeric indicies from `relativeStart` (or 0, if `relativeStart` is negative) up to the value of the `length` property of the object:

> 6. If relativeStart is negative, let k be max((len + relativeStart),0); else let k be min(relativeStart, len).
>
> 8. If relativeEnd is negative, let final be max((len + relativeEnd),0); else let final be min(relativeEnd, len).
>
> 10. Repeat, while k < final
>
> - (push obj[k] into the new array-like object being created)

So:

> Does [].slice.call only work on "one-dimensional" objects, or is there something else going on?

It will only work on objects with *numeric properties*. If you have non-numeric properties, they will not be iterated over with `slice`.

If you want to

> wrap a complicated object in an array of length 1 (i.e., the object is the only entry in the array)

then just use `[foo]`, eg:

```js
const foo = {"a":{"a1":1},"b":{"b1":2},length: 2};
const wrappedFoo = [foo];
console.log(wrappedFoo);
```

> Is there an "easy" way to turn {"a":{"a1":"foo"},"b":{"b1":"bar"}} into [{"a1":"foo"},{"b1":"bar"}]?

Use `Object.values` to extract the values of the object into an array:

```js
const obj = {"a":{"a1":"foo"},"b":{"b1":"bar"}};
const arr = Object.values(obj);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Fanstastic, and many thanks. What if I'm in a constructor, and am trying to use default values for parameters to populate the class properties . . . say I have:

`constructor(
   public authData = {
      "prop1": {"key1": 3},
      "prop2": {"key1": 4}
}`    
 
. . . but instead of `{"key1": 4}`, I want `[{"key1": 4}]`?

Comment: Take the `Object.values` of the object, and then use `.map` to surround each in an array, eg `.map(arr => [arr])`

Comment: Many thanks. That's super helpful. I will play around with this tomorrow to confirm. Hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `object` you are using as the argument of `call()` is passed as the `this` argument of `slice()` and it will work only over the numeric properties of the object as **CertainPerformance** already mentioned. If you use numeric properties it will work as you expect:

```js
let foo1 = {"0": 1, "1": 2, length: 2};
console.log([].slice.call(foo1));

let foo2 = {"0": {"a1":1}, "1": {"b1":2}, length: 2};
console.log([].slice.call(foo2));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

However that is a rare way of get what [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) already gives you:

```js
let foo1 = {"0": 1, "1": 2};
console.log(Object.values(foo1));

let foo2 = {"0": {"a1":1}, "1": {"b1":2}};
console.log(Object.values(foo2));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```